# i am not getting my desired output when i run my node.js code what is the mistake here?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

so I've been doin this bmiCalculator where I enter 2 numbers and these 2 numbers are calculated in my server and the answer is displayed but I have been facing troubling in receiving my output.when I click submit i am getting a list of all my files in the index of c but not the answer. Can someone please help me w this?

my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BMI calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <input type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my js code

```
let express = require("express")
let bodyParser = require("body-parser")
let app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("working")
})
app.get('/',function(request,respond){
    respond.sendFile(__dirname+"/bmiCalculator.html")
})
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    let num1 = Number(req.body.num1)
    let num2 = Number(req.body.num2)
    let result = num1/num2*num2
res.send(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to Express [res.send([body])](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) docs:

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array

You can't send a number by itself. So you could send a string using `result.toString()`

2. You should use `<input type="submit" value="submit">` to submit the form.

E.g.

`server.js`:

```js
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('working');
});
app.get('/', function(request, respond) {
  respond.sendFile(__dirname + '/bmiCalculator.html');
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  let num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  let num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  let result = (num1 / num2) * num2;
  res.send(result.toString());
});
```

`bmiCalculator.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BMI calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1">
      <input type="text" name="num2">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server logs after submit the form in client-side:

```js
working
{ num1: '1', num2: '2' }
```